# How to check http requests from a third party APK in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, web-scraping

I have downloaded a third party apk and I am trying to intercept and view API calls from this app. When using fiddler and other network analyzers android did not let me use the apps behind a proxy. Now I am tying to use android studio's network profiler, but i am not being able to wrap my head around how it works. Is there a known work around to intercept http requests from an arbitrary apk?

Answer (score 1):

Use NetCapture tool. If the App is available to only a particular region than you might have a problem but otherwise you shouldn't have any problem intercepting it. And one other thing if the server is using https connection than you will have encoded json which you have to decode the json.

Comment: using the app i was able to track the app's API endpoint url, but it gives me an encrypted sort of response that it says its SSL, I tried allowing auto parse packet data but to no success. How do i parse this request in order to get the body and headers?